# SQL query - splitting a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a novice when it comes to SQL queries, but have a problem that I need to solve but haven't found a solution to yet.

I have a database with contracts, basically looking like the row below. What it means is that we agreed to sell a commodity at a fixed price for the month Dec-March each winter for three winters, a total of 12 months.

```
ID  Type    From    To  Period  Units
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000
```

I would like to write a query so that I get a table like the one below, where I get one row for each month, with the number of units and an added column with the month for that row. Is this doable? If so, what would the query look like?

```
Br
CS

ID  Type    From    To  Period  Units   Month
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2016-12-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2017-01-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2017-02-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2017-03-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2017-12-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2018-01-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2018-02-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2018-03-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2018-12-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2019-01-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2019-02-01
1   VS  2016-12-01  2019-03-01  dec-mar 125000  2019-03-01
```

Comment: Are you sure SQL is the right tool for you?

Comment: One solution would be to build a `dates` table and `join` to it using `<=` and `>=`.  You could also do the same with a `numbers` table but a little more work involved.

Comment: No, I'm not sure that SQL is the right tool, are there tools better suited for this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This is quite easy in Postgres using `generate_series()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below script and get the result

```
declare @startDt date = '2016-12-01'
declare @endDt date = '2019-03-01'
declare @info table (id int, [type] varchar(5), [From] date, [To] date, Period varchar(10), units int)

insert into @info values (1, 'VS', @startDt, @endDt, 'dec-mar', 125000)

declare @dates table (dt date)
declare @mnts int = datediff(MONTH, @startDt, @endDt)

declare @i int = 0
while @i <= @mnts
begin
  declare @d1 date = dateadd(MONTH, @i, @startDt)
  if MONTH(@d1) >= MONTH(@startDt) or MONTH(@d1) <= MONTH(@endDt)
    insert into @dates values (@d1)
  set @i = @i + 1
end

select *
from @info cross join @dates
order by dt
```